# Im trying to get this code to do a multiple keyword search

Tags: php, mysql, search, keyword

When I type about three keywords or more it seems to only search the last keyword i.e `sydney+region+nsw` it will only search `nsw`.

I want it to search multiple keywords or the complete search term when inputted.

This is the code:

```
if($_REQUEST['searchkey']!="" && $_REQUEST['searchkey']=="search_record"){
    //Remove any html/javascript.
    $keyword = secureValue($_REQUEST['keyword']);    
    $cat_id = intval($_REQUEST['cat_level_root']);  
    $subcat_id = intval($_REQUEST['cat_level_one']);    
    $sub_subcat_id = intval($_REQUEST['cat_level_two']);
    $stateId = intval($_REQUEST['classi_state']);
    $hometownId = intval($_REQUEST['classi_zipcode']);
    $servicesId = intval($_REQUEST['classified_desc9']);
    $cityId = intval($_REQUEST['classi_city']);
    $priceId = intval($_REQUEST['classified_title9']);
    $ad_key = intval($_REQUEST['ad_id']);

    $types = array();
    $types_x = explode(" ",$keyword);
    $keyword = trim($_REQUEST['keyword']);
    foreach($types_x as $keyword) {
        $x++;
        if($x==0)
            $types[]=($keyword!="" && $keyword!="Enter Your Keywords..") ? " " : ""; 
    }
    $types=implode($types);
    $columns = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *  ";
    $sql = " FROM tbl_classified
        WHERE  clsd_sub_subcat_id=1395 AND CONCAT(classified_title, ' ', 
            classified_desc, '   ',  classified_type6, ' ', classified_title2, ' ",
            classified_type, ' ', classified_type2, ' ', classified_type3, ' ', 
            classified_desc3, ' ', classified_type5) LIKE '%$keyword%' 
            and classified_status='Active' 
            and paid_status!='Pending' 
        ORDER BY classified_post_date,classified_featured asc $types";
    $sql = $columns.$sql;
    $rs_classi=db_query($sql);
    $res_classi = mysql_fetch_array(db_query("Select FOUND_ROWS() as total"));
    $reccnt=$res_classi['total'];
}
```

Comment: Its a bit confusing what you do there... what is the value of $keyword at the point you define the $sql? Your issue, if I understand correctly, is with the query and the usage of your input. Also, you (i suppose) sanitize the input by  $keyword = secureValue($_REQUEST['keyword']); and afterwards redifine it with the raw post value... For your sql query, I think you would be better with a ...MATCH ... AGAINST ... set of parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You explode the keyword string with spaces. `$types_x = explode(" ",$keyword);`

Explode with `+` (eg. `explode("+", $keyword)`) or use [`urldecode`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) before explode.

Comment: That's great it worked! Something as simple as that. Thanks appreciate it.